# Group Theory-Group of Motions of plane

Tags: group-theory

I have a doubt in *Chapter 5, section 2 (Group Motions of the Plane) of Michael Artin*. *Page 159* has a paragraph which describes how computations in group $M$ of all rigid motions in a plane (translation, rotation, and reflection) can be done using symbols as given in the attached picture. While it is easy to understand the compositions ticked in green, I have not understood the compositions boxed in red. *References 2.3, 2.4* from the book also has been added to the picture.

Would be grateful for any help in understanding these.

[image]

Comment: Draw sketches for these compositions..

Comment: To convince yourself that the transformations are the same, you can just multiply the relevant matrices

Answer (score 1):

I sketched a little diagram for the case

$$
\rho_\theta t_a = t_{a'}\rho_\theta
$$

[image]

The parallelogram is just to show how $a' = \rho_\theta a$ is obtained: by rotating $a$. Using the same logic you can make sense of the other identity

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you